# How to authenticate the URLs that serves Static files in Hapi JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have a route as below which serves the static pages:

```
{
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/webapp/{param*}',
     config: {
         handler: {
             directory :{
                 path : Path.join(__dirname, '../../webapp/'),
                 index: true
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

So, I want to check if the user is logged in or not before it takes user to that url `"/webapp/#blabla"`.
User Can only access that url if user is logged in.

I tried to add `pre` option with a function in the above route but no luck.

```
 {
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/webapp/{param*}',
     pre:[{method:checkUrl, assign:'m1'}],
     config: {
         handler: {
             directory :{
                 path : Path.join(__dirname, '../../webapp/'),
                 index: true
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

And the checkUrl function is as:

```
var checkUrl = function(request, reply) {
     if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
       // redirect to login page     
       reply.redirect('/login');
     }
     return true;
}
```

Why is that i cannot get redirected to login page?

Comment: How do you determine if someone is "logged in" or not? Are you using hapi-auth-cookie?

Comment: Hi Matt.. I am a great fan of you.. I have read most of your blog.. :)

Comment: And i m using hapi-auth-cookie for authentication and request.auth.isAuthenticate determines if user is logged in or not

Comment: *Blushes*. Haha, Didn't know I had fans ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends slightly on which auth scheme you're using but the same principle applies. Here's an example using [hapi-auth-basic](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic) ([adapted from the example in the README](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic/blob/master/README.md)):

```
var Bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Path = require('path');
var Inert = require('inert');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000});

var users = {
    john: {
        username: 'john',
        password: '$2a$10$iqJSHD.BGr0E2IxQwYgJmeP3NvhPrXAeLSaGCj6IR/XU5QtjVu5Tm',   // 'secret'
        name: 'John Doe',
        id: '2133d32a'
    }
};

var validate = function (request, username, password, callback) {

    var user = users[username];
    if (!user) {
        return callback(null, false);
    }

    Bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isValid) {

        callback(err, isValid, { id: user.id, name: user.name });
    });
};

server.register([
    require('inert'), 
    require('hapi-auth-basic')
], function (err) {

    server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validateFunc: validate });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/webapp/{param*}',
        config: {
            auth: 'simple',            // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT
            handler: {
                directory :{
                    path : Path.join(__dirname, 'files'),
                    index: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    server.start(function (err) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log('Server started!');
    })
});
```

The important point is just to add an `auth` property to the route config with the strategy name. It's the same as you would do for any routes. Have a read of [this tutorial](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth), it might clear it up for you.

Are you able to adapt that to your needs?

Comment: Thank you..right now i m using auth: 'session' and i think its working before that i had auth: { mode: 'try', strategy:'session' }